# How to determine if an SSRS text report parameter is blank?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I'm having trouble determining if an SSRS 2016 text report parameter is null or blank. Here is my parameter's properties:

[image: Parameter properties]

And this is the expression I'm using to display it. If it's non-null or non-blank I want to display it as a formatted date, otherwise "N/A".

```
=IIF((Parameters!EndDateTime.Value = "") OR IsNothing(Parameters!EndDateTime.Value), "N/A", Format(CDate(Parameters!EndDateTime.Value),"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
```

[image: Expression Setup]

But when I run the report I get "#Error" if the value is blank:

[image: Report error]

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `IIF()` function evaluates always both arguments. Here you will find more information about it: [IIF Evaluation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11840.ssrs-iif-function-evaluates-both-true-false.aspx)

You either go with the `IsDate()` function to check if it is a date before you convert it or you can use a `Switch()` statement.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I think it was this and a combination of the use of CDate(). I ended up going with a switch().